# MySQL CentOS : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, centos

I installed MySQL in CentOS using `sudo yum install mysql-server` and logged into MySQL using `mysql -u root -p` and gave blank password. It's not allowing me to use MySQL database or select users/update password/create database.

```sql
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('*****') WHERE user='root';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


[centos@****~]$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  mysqld.service
[centos@****~]$ sudo mysqld_safe
151026 14:40:32 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
151026 14:40:32 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
[centos@*****~]$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 152
Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql>
```

Error Again:

```
[centos@~]$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  mysqld.service
[centos~]$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 25678
[centos~]$ 151026 14:53:07 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
151026 14:53:07 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
[centos@~]$ sudo mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 160
Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: you don't change the user db manually. `set password for root@localhost=password('*****')`

Comment: It's throwing me an error when I do that.                                         mysql> set password for root@localhost=password('****');
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
3. `sudo mysql -u root`
4. Setup new MySQL root user password

   ```
   use mysql;
   update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
   flush privileges;
   quit
   ```
5. Stop MySQL Server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` (if any error use `sudo`)
6. Start MySQL server and test it: `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Steps 1,2 and 3 are successful. But in step 4, when I run "use MySQL" I'm getting error. mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: I edited my question and included the steps you mentioned. Please let me know if you need additional information. thank you

Comment: try without `use mysql;`

Comment: without "use MySQL" it's throwing me No database selected error. mysql>  update user set password=PASSWORD("*****")  where User='root';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: use `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` then `mysql -u root` then try 4th again

Comment: ]$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 25371
[centos@****~]$ 151026 14:49:21 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
151026 14:49:21 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Comment: Error again. Edited my question with details.

Comment: run this `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root";`

Comment: and then `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: @user527696 what happen any progress??

Comment: Nope :( Even without -p it's not working. When I try to start sercidce it's throwing error "$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysqld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."

Comment: better you reinstall it

Comment: In 'journalctl -xn' it says " mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists"

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Password set, you can't give the -p Parameter with the mysql command. Start it only with `mysql -u root`